# Asp.Net Core url referer is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to get url referer `var referer = Request.Headers["Referer"]`.
I already used this in my other projects, but this time there is no such header there. Maybe i should add something to Configure method, but i can't find any info about it.

Comment: Referer is [not required](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-5.5.2); maybe it's just not there for the request(s) you're using it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Try this:

```
string referer = Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem: I found in a old stackoverflow post 2010
that the referer is not set unless a link button is clicked
return redirect('...') only provided a blank value. In my case
I had to have the sending app use a special html page with a href
clicked by a javascript when page was loading. Tested and working.
Just wanted to help clarify this issue. Hope this helps someone.