# Inline authentication in razor

Tags: asp.net, razor, webforms, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm coming from VB.NET webforms on .NET 4 to C# and ASP.NET Core 6 Razor pages.

Our users authenticate via network information injected in the headers.

Previously we'd check for a valid header in `global.asax`. If it was valid we'd allow them to view the address they typed.

User goes to `myAwesomePage.aspx`

```
'global.asax
If HttpContext.Current.Session Is Nothing then
    'log the user in using header data
else 
    'go to newAccount.aspx
end if
```

In Razor, I can't seem to allow the user to get to `myAwesomePage.cshtml`

```
//program.cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("myApp")
    .AddCookie("myApp", options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "myApp";
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
        // can I get the intended page here somehow? I don't think I can...
    });

//login
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(){
    string referer = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"].toString(); //this is always "" so I can't use it to redirect the user.
    //other code
}
```

How do I authenticate the user and redirect using razor? TIA.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thanks I've seen that, it doesn't have the answer.

Answer (score 0):

My original attempt that I got from here: [Asp.Net Core url referer is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61859203/asp-net-core-url-referer-is-empty)  wasn't working.
Changing

```
HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"].toString();
```

to

```
HttpContext.Request.Query["returnUrl"]
```

Solved the problem.

`Headers["Referer"]` vs `Query["returnUrl"]` is a problem for another day.